# Можно ли в android написать приложение без графического интерфейс

Tags: android

Мне нужно написать приложение которое работало бы в фоне, без GUI, выполняло сетевый запросы на сервер с периодичностью в 5 минут, в зависимости результата, выполняла нотификацию. То есть сделали запрос, дынные не валидные (к примеру), показываем notification. Возможно ли это и если да, то как?

Answer (score 3):

Создать [сервис](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) с [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) и запускать его:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
    }
}

public class YourService extends Service {
    [...]

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // do your jobs here
        return  return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет! Нужно что бы сам компонент приложения, как процесс работал в фоне всегда, вне зависимости от того работает сейчас родительское приложение которое его (сервис тот же к примеру)  запустило или нет, как daemon'ы в linux. А этот сервис, падает когда мы закрываем родительское приложение.